# Which version of Visual Studio 2010 contains Visual Basic SharePoint Templates

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

Quick question...

Does anybody know which version of Visual Studio 2010 contains the full set of Visual Basic SharePoint Templates? I am about to embark on a project to create Visual Web Parts to be used in a SharePoint report.

At the moment I am using Visual Studio 2008 and even though the WSPBuilder is installed none of the relevant SharePoint templates are present.

Having searched SO and the web, most advise to install the templates via the Visual Studio command prompt:

```
    devenv /installvstemplates
```

Alas the Visual Studio command prompt is also missing from my VS2008 installation.

So, the question remains: which version of VS2010 contains what I need for pain-free SharePoint development? There is a rather large price different between VS2010 Professional and VS2010 Premium, so can anyone tell me if the cheaper version (VS2010 Professional) contains all the Sharepoint templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I am using VS Professional with the SharePoint templates.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer Lee. VS2010 Professional did indeed have the SharePoint templates and saved us a bunch of money by not having to purchase the full-fat Premium edition!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Visual Studio 2010 professional has the SharePoint Templates

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have VS2010 Professional installed I have subsequently found a link to a Microsoft download that would have probably met my needs completely.

[Visual Studio 2008 extensions for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21082)

Nevermind.

Comment: No, that link is for Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: As stated in my question, I _was_ using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Oh, i see. You're saying that the link would have helped you with VS2008, not VS2010.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying. Unfortunately I found the link too late, after upgrading to VS2010 Professional from VS2008.